# Print all elements in rowmapper in java

Tags: java, database, oracle

How to get the data in rowmapper and print in log statements? Can any one please help ? I tried to see in various blogs but didnt help. Thanks in advance.

Can any one please suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public interface LogDAO extends AbstractDAO<TblLogEntity, TblLogEntity1>
{
    void logEvent(String id, String action, String oldValue, String newValue);
}

And you can get data to log like this:
LtblTableEntity e;
logDAO.logEvent(e.getId().toString(), "action", e.getName(), "NewName");
```